# Convert time into minutes and seconds

Tags: c++, oop, most-vexing-parse

I made a code to convert time into minutes and seconds using constructor. In output I'm getting time in seconds but its not displaying time in minutes and can't figured out my mistake so anyone can help me out...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
public:
    Time(int);
    Time(float);
};

Time::Time(int t)
{
    cout << "Time in seconds: " << t*60*60 << "\n";
}
Time::Time(float t)
{
    cout << "Time in Minutes: " << int(t*60) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int hr;
    cout << "Enter the time in Hours: ";
    cin >> hr;
    Time t1(hr);
    Time t2(float(hr));
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your output.

Comment: OUTPUT:sh-4.2# g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp                                                                                                   
sh-4.2# main                                                                                                                           
Enter the time in Hours: 4                                                                                                             
Time in seconds: 14400                                                                                                                 
sh-4.2# g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp

Comment: This is _not_ what classes are for.

Comment: @Light At least it is very creative ... Ineffective but creative

Answer (score 3):

You aren't typecasting correctly. You need to typecast by putting the desired type in parentheses, *not* by trying to use it as a function. For example, you'd need to do this:

```
Time t2((float) hr);

cout << "Time in Minutes: " << (int) t*60 << "\n";
```

While `Time t2(float(hr));` is legal, it's a function prototype because this is a [vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse#Example_with_functions). It is equivalent to `Time t2(float hr);`, which means that `t2` is a function that takes a `float` called "hr" and returns a `Time`. This has no effect since such a function is never implemented or called.

If this seems absurd, here's a way to think about it that can help. Consider this code:

```
Time t2 (float (*hr));
```

Clearly this is a perfectly normal way to declare `t2` as a function that takes a pointer to a `float` called "hr". Well, shouldn't it also be legal without the `*`? And the C++ grammar rule is that if something can be a prototype, it is.

Comment: I thought int(..) was a constructor for an integer type ? why is it not correct to us it here ?

Comment: for instance there no difference seems to be made before int(..) or (int) .. ?
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/
(as pointed out in the comment that just got removed)

Comment: But we are using constructors for time. and it doesn't show that it's a constructor and the variable are also not declared like this...??

Comment: You aren't typecasting correctly. You need to typecast by putting the desired type in parentheses, not by trying to use it as a function. - The functional programming cast is equivalent to the c cast

Answer (score 1):

Should works :

```
Time t2((float)hr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Time::Time(int hour){
    cout << "Time in seconds: " << hour*60*60 << "\n";
    cout << "Time in minutes: " << hour*60 << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding

```
Time::Time(float t)
{
    cout << "Time in Minutes: " << float(t*60) << "\n";
}
```

tell me if it works..